# Add span to menu inside li tag and outside anchor tag

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I had a menu:

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <a href="">News</a>
  <span></span>
 </li>
</ul>
```

How can i add span tag like this in li tag and outside anchor tag?Im making a mobile click menu but if i handle click on li tag , i cant click to anchor tag

Comment: `$('li').append('<span/>')`?

Comment: Tks both of u for helping :D.Problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("ul li a").after("<span></span>");
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/a5qqwxq1/1/).